# Why is Kubernetes pod taking more memory than it's processes take?

Tags: php, kubernetes, out-of-memory, fpm

Our stack is basically nginx + php-fpm.
We have the same setup in many projects, and it works fine.
Except in one project it keeps going our of memory.

The PHP-FPM container keeps accumulating memory until the php-fpm processes start to get OOMKilled ending with pod termination.
We have a discrepancy between cloud monitoring and `top` in containers.
In monitoring (Google Cloud Metrics Explorer) shows ever-rising mem charts
while `top` inside the container is very modest.

[image: Pod memory]

Notice that `k9a` reports also high usage for one of the pods in `%MEM/L` column.

[image: k9s pods overview]

Meanwhile `top` reports are very similar between "healthy" and "unhealthy" pods.

Healthy:
[image: healthy container top output]

Unhealthy:
[image: unhealthy container top output]

Notice that the amount of php-fpm processes and their mem consumption (200-250) is roughly the same in both pods.

Unhealthy container log:

[image: unhealthy container log]

The number of PHP-FPM processes is limited to a small number. We monitored mem consumption of individual processes over time, and they all look the same:

[image: php-fpm process memory usage over time]

The memory is always freed by php-fpm after serving a request.

We have noticed, that the memory climb is increased by traffic. No traffic - flat chart.

It seems, that if the pod does not receive traffic for a longer period of time, it starts to free it.

We noticed, that we can simulate the problem by allocating shared memory. Except in the problematic container, we don't see any shared memory being allocated. `ipcs` is empty.

We noticed that the issue goes away by using Memcached by the application.

What is perplexing to us - where is the hidden memory? The discrepancy between processes and the pod. How could we see the "dark" memory?

EDIT:

We did one more experiment with CPU with a bit surprising results:

[image]

Comment: I am not really seeing the discrepancy. The FPM processes appear to add up to about what you have in your graph, but really you should be looking at RSS instead of VSZ.

Comment: In the last chart there are RSS and VSZ. They follow nicely each other.

Comment: The discrepancy - check `k9s` chart `%MEM/L` column.